# selenium testNG retry with incorrect result account

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-eclipse

I am using testNG 6.9.10 that installed in Eclipse.
I was trying to use retry to make sure the failed tests could run maxcount times that defined.
See below codes.

```
public class TestRetry implements IRetryAnalyzer {
    private int retryCount = 0;
    private int maxRetryCount = 1;

    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {

        if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
            retryCount++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Test(retryAnalyzer = TestRetry.class)
    public void testGenX() {
        Assert.assertEquals("google", "google");
    }

    @Test(retryAnalyzer = TestRetry.class)
    public void testGenY() {
        Assert.assertEquals("hello", "hallo");

    }
}
```

I got below result:

```
===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

But seems like the result count with some problems. I want below:

```
===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

I tried to defined the listeners to implement it, something like to override the onFinish function. You may find it in http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/retry-listener-failed-tests-count-update
But finally not works.

can someone who had met this could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working fine, i hope there is some problem on listener usage. I created TestRetry as same like you but with out @Test methods.

```
 public class TestRetry implements IRetryAnalyzer{

private int retryCount = 0;
private int maxRetryCount = 1;

@Override
public boolean retry(ITestResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
        retryCount++;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Created Listener class

```
 public class TestListener implements ITestListener{

@Override
public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Set<ITestResult> failedTests = context.getFailedTests().getAllResults();
    for (ITestResult temp : failedTests) {
        ITestNGMethod method = temp.getMethod();
        if (context.getFailedTests().getResults(method).size() > 1) {
            failedTests.remove(temp);
        } else {
            if (context.getPassedTests().getResults(method).size() > 0) {
                failedTests.remove(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart(ITestContext arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTestStart(ITestResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Finally my test class with those methods

```
  public class RunTest {


@Test(retryAnalyzer = TestRetry.class)
public void testGenX() {
    Assert.assertEquals("google", "google");
}

@Test(retryAnalyzer = TestRetry.class)
public void testGenY() {
    Assert.assertEquals("hello", "hallo");

}

}
```

Executed this RunTest from testng.xml file by specifying the my custom listener

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite1" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
<listeners>
   <listener class-name="com.test.TestListener"/>
</listeners>

<test name="TestA">
<classes>
  <class name="com.test.RunTest"/>
</classes>
 </test> <!-- Test -->
 </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

[image]

Please have a try..

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tired again the same as you provided, but still with the wrong output, is your result like below?
**Suite1**
**Total tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Skips: 1**
and  what the testNG version you are using?

Comment: [TestNG] Running:
  D:\MyFramework\testing\testng1.xml


===============================================
Suite1
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

Comment: added result image also and here info..  TestNG 6.8.6.20141201_2240 org.testng.eclipse.feature.group Cedric Beust

Comment: thanks again. Looks like your result is correct. I was using the testng plugin that for eclipse is   TestNG 6.9.10.201512240000 org.testng.eclipse.feature.group Cedric Beust.  Not the testng that included in selenium standaldon server. But still failed. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi Murali, I am running 2 tests using parallel execution. I try it but only one test run again after fail and second test is running only one time. how we can use it with parallel execution?

Comment: @FarhanGhaffar could you please provide bit more information? i am not able to get your point. or you can go for another question with details

Answer (score 0):

@murali could please see my codes below? I really cannot see any difference.
The CustomLinstener.java

```
package cases;
import java.util.Set;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class CustomLinstener implements ITestListener{

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        Set<ITestResult> failedTests = context.getFailedTests().getAllResults();
        for (ITestResult temp : failedTests) {
            ITestNGMethod method = temp.getMethod();
            if (context.getFailedTests().getResults(method).size() > 1) {
                failedTests.remove(temp);
            } else {
                if (context.getPassedTests().getResults(method).size() > 0) {
                    failedTests.remove(temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

The RunTest.java

```
package cases;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class RunTest {


@Test(retryAnalyzer = TestRetry.class)
public void testGenX() {
    Assert.assertEquals("google", "google");
}

@Test(retryAnalyzer = TestRetry.class)
public void testGenY() {
    Assert.assertEquals("hello", "hallo");

}

}
```

The TestRetry.java

```
package cases;

import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class TestRetry implements IRetryAnalyzer{

private int retryCount = 0;
private int maxRetryCount = 1;

@Override
public boolean retry(ITestResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
        retryCount++;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Finally the XML. I right click it and run as the testNG suite.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite1" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">

    <test name="TestA">
        <classes>
            <class name="cases.RunTest" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
        <listeners>
        <listener class-name="cases.CustomLinstener" />
    </listeners>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: @murali seleniumtrainer, I post this answer , could you help to review?

Comment: Hi, it looks like every thing is fine. it may be due to change in testng version, for safe side just try deleting temp. In eclipse i dont getting testng suite on right click in in run as. i simply click on run button on top in eclipse. in my system using JDK 7

Comment: @muraliseleniumtrainer, thanks for the warm help. It is enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for TestNG's [`IRetryAnalyzer`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IRetryAnalyzer.html) does not specify test reporting behavior:

> Interface to implement to be able to have a chance to retry a failed test.

There are no mention of "retries" on http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html and searching across the entire [testng.org](http://testng.org/) site only returns links to the documentation of and references to `IRetryAnalyzer` (see [site:testng.org retry - Google Search](https://www.google.com/#q=site:testng.org+retry)).

As there is no documentation for how a retried test is reported we cannot make many sound expectations. Should each attempt appear in the test results? If so, is each attempt except for the last attempt marked as a skip and the last as either a success or a failure? It isn't documented. The behavior is undefined and it could change with any TestNG release in subtle or abrupt ways.

As such, I recommend using a tool other than TestNG for retry logic.

e.g. You can [Spring Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) (which can be used independently of other [Spring](https://spring.io/) projects):

**TestRetry.java**

```java
public class TestRetry {
    private static RetryOperations retryOperations = createRetryOperations();

    private static RetryOperations createRetryOperations() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(createRetryPolicy());
        return retryTemplate;
    }

    private static RetryPolicy createRetryPolicy() {
        int maxAttempts = 2;
        Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> retryableExceptions =
                Collections.singletonMap(AssertionError.class, true);
        return new SimpleRetryPolicy(maxAttempts, retryableExceptions);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGenX() {
        runWithRetries(context -> {
            Assert.assertEquals("google", "google");
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testGenY() {
        runWithRetries(context -> {
            Assert.assertEquals("hello", "hallo");
        });
    }

    private void runWithRetries(RetryRunner<RuntimeException> runner) {
        retryOperations.execute(runner);
    }
}
```

**RetryRunner.java**

```java
/**
 * Runner interface for an operation that can be retried using a
 * {@link RetryOperations}.
 * <p>
 * This is simply a convenience interface that extends
 * {@link RetryCallback} but assumes a {@code void} return type.
 */
interface RetryRunner<E extends Throwable> extends RetryCallback<Void, E> {
    @Override
    default Void doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws E {
        runWithRetry(context);
        return null;
    }

    void runWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws E;
}
```

**Console Output**

```
===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Spring Retry may look slightly more complicated at first but it provides very flexible [features and API](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry#features-and-api) and enables [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) of the test retry logic and the test reporting.